# Can I add logic to a rails 3 hidden field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logic, hidden-field

I have a form to submit data and I want to automatically set one field depending on whether all the other fields are filled out or not. If they are all completed, the field will be "complete", if not it will be set to "draft".

So I have the hidden field like this:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :status, :value => "draft" %>
```

to make it default to draft. BUT, can I add logic that says it will be "complete" if all the other fields are filled out and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no other client-side events have to take place when the the status changes, it would be best practice to place this kind of business logic inside of your model as a callback, e.g. (replace `Foo` and `fieldx` with your model and field names):

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :default_status

  def default_status
    if field1 && field2 && field3 && field4
      self.status = 'completed'
    else
       self.status = 'draft'
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: You mean model I guess but yes, that looks great. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed the syntax as well, should be `&&` instead of `||` because we want the existence of all of the attributes rather than any one attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it on the client-side with jquery, assuming your model is named foo:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name*="otherfields"]').on('change', function() {
      var othercount = 0;
      $('input[name*="otherfields"]').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
          othercount += 1;
      });
      if ( othercount == 2 ) 
        $('#foo_status').attr('checked',true)
      else
        $('#foo_status').attr('checked',false)
    });
  });
</script>

<%= check_box_tag :item1 , '1', false, :name=>'otherfields[1]' %>    
<%= check_box_tag :item2 , '2', false, :name=>'otherfields[2]' %>
<%= f.hidden_field :status, :value => "draft" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that in the controller.

Lets say the form directs you to the create action.

In the create action of the controller, you can check if all the fields are completed by looking at `params` and then use `if` statement to assign appropriate value to `status` before saving

Comment: I agree that this should take place server-side. However, I don't think that logic belongs in the controller, sounds a lot better off in the model as a callback.

Answer (score 0):

This would be done with javascript, possibly jQuery. However, why would you design it this way? Could you not do this on the server side?